# Finding the changes done between two commits in GIT

Tags: git, shell, unix

Suppose in master there are two files are present in the master branch in GIT named as
file1.txt , file2.txt

In develop also the same files are present ie file1.txt, file2.txt.

Now I added some new files i.e file3.txt , file4.txt in develop and edited file2.txt , and pushed to develop branch only in the same commit.

Can anyone help in git commmand which can give the difference in between the two commit points in develop branch.
I am expecting the the result as mentioned below:-

file2.txt

file3.txt

file4.txt

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
git diff --name-only commit1Id commit2Id
```

where **commit1Id** and **commit2Id** are the hashes of the 2 commits. You can find those using:

```
git log
```